# discord.py rewrite | How would I make this into an integer?

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I am trying to make a command which activates a random number guesser game. Obviously, I am stuck in the first few lines. I have written what I THINK will work, however it may be blatantly wrong. I want it to change the message on the discord server to an int, so it will work in my if statement.

It's my first time making a bot in with discord.py, so I am running into many obstacles. I am not fully sure what the error is telling me, so I haven't been able to try any fixes. This is the code:

```
async def numgame(context):
    number = random.randint(1,100)
    for guess in range(0,5):
        await context.send('Pick a number between 1 and 100')
        Message = await client.wait_for('message')
        Message = int(Message)
        if Message.cleant_content > number:
            await context.send(guess + ' guesses left...')
            asyncio.sleep(1)
            await context.send('Try going lower')
            asyncio.sleep(1)
       elif Message.clean_content < number:
            await context.send(guess + ' guesses left...')
            asyncio.sleep(1)
            await context.send('Try going higher')
            asyncio.sleep(1)
        else:
            await context.send('You guessed it! Good job!')
    if number != Message:
        await context.send('Tough luck!')
```

Whenever I do the command in my discord server, my shell gives me this error:

> discord.ext.commands.errors.CommandInvokeError: Command raised an exception: TypeError: int() argument must be a string, a bytes-like object or a number, not 'Message'

I am not too sure what it is telling me. As stated, I would like "Message" to be an integer, but I get the error. but help would be appreciated!
[still a beginner, don't be too harsh :(]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`wait_for('message')` returns a `Message` object, which `int` doesn't know how to handle yet.  You need to convert `Message.content` to an int instead.  Just below is your code with some other changes:

```
def check(message):
    try:
        int(message.content)
        return True
    except ValueError:
        return False

@bot.command()
async def numgame(context):
    number = random.randint(1,100)
    for guess in range(0,5):
        await context.send('Pick a number between 1 and 100')
        msg = await client.wait_for('message', check=check)
        attempt = int(msg.content)
        if attempt > number:
            await context.send(str(guess) + ' guesses left...')
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            await context.send('Try going lower')
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
       elif attempt < number:
            await context.send(str(guess) + ' guesses left...')
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
            await context.send('Try going higher')
            await asyncio.sleep(1)
        else:
            await context.send('You guessed it! Good job!')
            break 
    else:
        await context.send("You didn't get it")
```

Comment: after changing it to "await context.send(str(guess) + ' guesses left...')", it worked properly! Thank you so much